# Laravel ORM relationship returns null on Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models User and UserType declared as follows:

```
class User extends Model {
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function company() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Company', 'company_id', 'company_id');
    }

    public function userType() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserType', 'user_type_id', 'user_type_id');
    }
}

class UserType extends Model {
    protected $table = 'user_type';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_type_id';
}
```

Now, I query the relationships using:

```
User::with('userType', 'company')->all()
```

Strangely, I get the company but userType is always null.
The MySQL query log shows that Laravel was able to get the user_type record.

The only difference between *company* and *userType* relationships are the data type of the primary keys. *company.company_id* is numeric while *user_type.user_type_id* is a string.
I think it is related to the data type of the keys however, I have a similar setup on Laravel 5.1 and it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel supports non-numeric primary keys but you need to set:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

on your model class.
I corrected the issue by changing UserType definition to:

```
class UserType extends Model {
    protected $table = 'user_type';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_type_id';
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue i notice with your relationship is that the first user_type_id you have passed to the hasOne function is wrong because you have the user_type_id as the primary key of the user_type table. The second argument of the hasone must be the foreign key of the parent table which is the user. So if you have anything like user_id in the user_type table use that instead.

But if thats not the case and user rather belongs to UserType then you have to change the hasOne to belongsTo.

Comment: The issue is indeed the data type as I have initially guessed. See my answer.